# GROUP BY en SQLServer no funciona igual que en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Me explico: Cuando hago un `GROUP BY` con MySQL, puedo seleccionar campos que no pueden ser agrupados, como descripciones (varchars), y el resultado muestra, de todos los valores agrupados, el primero que encontra.

Pero ahora me encuentro con SQL Server y resulta que el mismo `group by` da error, según el motivo, porque "no sabe" qué hacer con esos campos si no se les ha aplicado una función de agrupación como SUM, AVG, COUNT...

Un ejemplo:

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
ID  GRUPO   VALOR   DESCRIPCION
--------------------------------
1   1       10      Prueba1
2   1       20      Prueba2
3   2       10      Prueba3
4   2       20      Prueba4
```

Y ejecuto la siguiente select:

```
SELECT GRUPO, AVG(VALOR), DESCRIPCION FROM `GroupBy` group by GRUPO;
```

Con esta select, en MySQL obtengo:

```
GRUPO   AVG(VALOR)  DESCRIPCION
-------------------------------
1       15.0        Prueba1
2       15.0        Prueba3
```

Pero en SQL Server obtengo:

```
SQL Error 8120: La columna "DESCRIPCION" de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer un `GROUP BY` en SQL Server que me devuelva el mismo resultado que me daría en MySQL?

Comment: Si la hay, pero no tan facil. En realidad mysql viola como deberia funcionar un groupby (access hace lo mismo). En una base de datos no hay definicion de primero y ultimo, por lo tanto, que campo deberia traerte una base de datos?

Comment: En tu ejemplo, si agrupas por grupo, no hay un valor logico para traer en descripcion... mysql hace lo que quiere, pero eso ni asegura que traiga siempre lo mismo.

Comment: Entiendo. En ese caso adquirí una mala práctica al aprenderlo desde MySQL.

Comment: El problema con el que me encuentro es que, además de esos campos, tengo un campo de FECHA y un campo de PRECIO. Lo que pretendo es que después de agrupar, se muestre el PRECIO más reciente en base a la FECHA más reciente.

Comment: Ok Alberto. y con la descripcion que hacemos? porque eso si se puede hacer. pone por favor un ejemplo claro de datos de entrada y lo que esperas como salida.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar el siguiente código, para tu descripción;

```
SELECT GRUPO, AVG(VALOR) AS 'AVG', MIN(DESCRIPCION) AS 'DESCRIPCION' 
FROM [group by] group by GRUPO
```

Si quisiera por fecha mas reciente seria algo parecido a:

```
SELECT a.GRUPO,a.[AVG Valor],b.Descripcion,b.Precio,a.Fecha  FROM (SELECT
GRUPO, AVG(VALOR) AS [AVG Valor], max(Fecha) AS fecha FROM [group  by] GROUP BY Grupo) a INNER JOIN [group by] b 
ON a.Fecha=b.fecha and  a.GRUPO=b.GRUPO
```

Comment: Esto resolveria el problema, si OP quisiera la menor descripcion. que no es lo que pidio.

Answer (score -1):

Unicamente te falta agregar el campo `Descripcion`, estas solicitando incluir que te muestre grupo y descripción pero solo esta agrupando grupo, intenta lo siguiente:

```
SELECT GRUPO, AVG(VALOR), DESCRIPCION FROM `GroupBy` group by GRUPO, DESCRIPCION;
```

Comment: No funciona. Al agregar DESCRIPCION a los criterios de agrupación, se separan las diferentes descripciones en grupos.